# Running userscripts in Android

Tags: android, javascript, web-browser

What software will allow me to run userscripts in Android? I like using Chrome, so if there is a Chrome-for-Android extension that allows userscripts that would be great, but if you know of a different browser that supports userscripts that would make for a good answer also.

( *I'm looking to use a [certain script](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/MY.Referencer.user.js) so I could use SE better* ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

I use the ***Scriptish*** addon to *Firefox* for this kind of job on the desktop. Luckily, there seems to be a [Scriptish addon for Firefox on Android](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/android/addon/scriptish/versions/) as well. Same applies to [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/android/addon/greasemonkey/versions/), which is another Firefox addon to run userscripts in.

Which one of the two to chose is rather a subjective decision. They have common roots (*Scriptish* is a fork of *Greasemonkey*), both are still maintained, both (roughly) cover the same field. UserScripts that work with one of them, usually also work with the other the same way.

I don't know about a solution for Chrome on Android – so using any of the two mentioned addons would mean you'd have to switch to Firefox. As you mentioned that being an option, I'd say the two fulfill all of your requirements – though I didn't try them myself *on Android*.

As a bonus: Here's a Youtube tutorial on [How To Install Greasemonkey In Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjCqjgWF_ck) :)

Comment: I finally got around to downloading Firefox for Android....I went to the add-on center: Scriptish is "not updated for Firefox 33.0," and Greasemonkey is "not compatible with Firefox 33.1." I'll watch your Youtube tutorial, maybe they'll help.

Comment: That's always the hunt with the crazy version bumping since FF started with that (all 6 weeks a new major release cannot be called anything but crazy). Scriptish at least has a "dev port" you could install – I'm just not sure whether they maintain it for Android as well.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks! ....is there any way to install a previous version of FF on Android?

Comment: If you find one, sure. But there's also the possibility to install "incompatible" addons by e.g. setting `extensions.checkCompatibility.*` to `false` (with the `*` replaced by your current FF version, e.g. `33.0` – or using the [checkCompatibility addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/) to have that applied automatically (not sure whether the latter is available for FF on Android).

Answer (score 0):

My app [Subhash Browser & Feed Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vsubhash.droid.subhashbrowser) supports both user scripts and user styles (CSS). You need to first convert the Javascript to bookmarklet format, save it in a file with .js extension and place it the app's User JS folder. However, extremely big JS files such as the one linked by you may not work. If it is a new phone, then the app will be using Chrome internally.

[image: User JS options in]