# Twitter for nearline people

Tags: twitter

I am not online 24-7, and I really only want to check Twitter once or twice a day.

But when I do I only see the last hour of tweets in my feed and most of them are a waste of electrons.

Is there a way I can filter the tweets in my feed so the top tweets in my feed are important tweets that were tweeted since last time I checked? (Important could be defined as retweeted/liked 5 or more, or it could be a Reddit-like rating system with exponential fall off, or a filter, that I can train by cliking "I do not want to see stuff like this"/"I love it").

Maybe a custom Twitter client?

Preferably it should be [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Free_Software_Definition) with at least the same features as the web client from Twitter currently has.

- Must run on Windows
- Must sort tweets since last log in by importance or weed out unimportant tweets
- Should be [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Free_Software_Definition)
- Good if runs on Android or GNU/Linux
- May be web app

Answer (score -1):

I have created a [read-only Twitter client](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26634/19586). It is a localhost web app that generates RSS feeds and HTML search results. It is available as a Android app and as a desktop Java software (Linux/Windows/Mac). It is free but not open.

I have [another browser+feed reader app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/26636/19586) for Android, which has a button to delete read messages. This is a manual option. It does not meet the second condition. The deleted messages are not really deleted just hidden. The feed reader has a text-based filter too.